# Text overflows when we increase Font Size and Display size from Display Setting

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

We have 10 different textview with value 95,96......100,101,105 display everything is fine if Font Size and Display Size is Default.
But as soon as we increase Font Size and Display Size to Large or Largest all 3 char value like 100,101...105 are split in the second line like for 100, 10 is first line and 0 in the second line due to it the UI look odd.

We try to as`android:maxLines="1"` but after that the last char is cut/hide like for 100 only 10 is display. We also use AutoTextSizing android solution

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
```

But with this solution also has one problem all 3 char value 100...105 are showing in small and all char 95...99 is big

Now I am looking for another solution for my problem. I want all text 95...105 should be the similar size and in one line only its size also increase decrease when user change the Font size and Display size. from Display Setting.

Comment: use singleLine=true and remove maxLine=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this method in your activity. When ever a user changes the screen Display or TextSize it changes the configuration settings for the system and then your app also picks that configuration settings and in your whole app the size of font gets bigger or smaller. It can disturb your apps looks. If you want to set same configurations then you can implement the below code.
You can change the font size by setting the value of **config.fontScale** = your choice;
you can check for **fontScale** on different screen sizes.

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        Log.d(TAG, "attachBaseContext: ");
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);

        Log.v(TAG, "attachBaseContext: Applying new configuration");
        Resources res = newBase.getResources();
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.fontScale = 1.0f;
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining separate text sizes in the `dimens.xml` like
`values-hdpi` -> `dimens.xml` ,
`values-xhdpi` -> `dimens.xml`
and so on. 
If it's still not working define text size in `dp` instead of `sp`.